# Displaying data in a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

I am building an application using C#.NET and WPF. There is a page called "Update Question Database" which allows a user to view, add, and edit questions.

When viewing a question, the four options and the correct options are displayed in textboxes. 
However, the length of the answer is more than the width of the textbox. How can I display that hidden part to my user?

I've tried but cannot set the multiline property of textbox to true. There is no multiline option.

Comment: can you post your textbox tag plz..

Answer (score 1):

The normal TextBox supports this, you just have to enable it. I think it's TextWrapping or AcceptsReturn that turns it on.

Comment: Thankyou akash88 .what about isHitTestVisible property of textBox

Comment: Please have a look on msdn:     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you are work in WPF so you have set `property` in textbox

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
AcceptsReturn="True"
```

e.g.

```
<TextBox Height="66" Margin="563,46,265,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```